# Get user information in PayPal sandbox environment

Tags: json, curl, paypal, paypal-sandbox

This is related to PayPal's API to get user information in sandbox environment as described here - https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#get-user-information

`curl -sk https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/identity/openidconnect/userinfo/?schema=openid \
-H "Content-Type:application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer <valid_access_token>"`

I get a user_id in the json response, but rest of the other user attributes such as name, given_name, family_name are removed. Like so

`{
    "user_id": "https://www.paypal.com/webapps/auth/identity/user/eyeTNlAeNRNDMpHBW6OCUyA-d7hsvZjChNONOiujnhU"
}`

How can I get rest of those attributes?

Comment: I face same problem. any solution for it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get these information, you need to select these attributes in your REST APP on developer.paypal.com site. [image]

Comment: I select all the attribute in my Rest APP but i face same problem. I am unable to get email id from access token.